Accessing member structs elements and modifying them
I have a struct in the following format
typedef struct small {
    int a;
} small;

typedef struct large {
    small* s;
    int b;
} large;

I would like to write a function which will modify the variable a. However in the function declaration/signature I would like to have small along the lines of
void modifyA(small* s, int newVal){
  s->a = newVal;
}

I would like to keep the modifyA function common to be supplied with both large and small. Is there a way to achieve this for large as input to modifyA function?
For example, I want
int main(){
  large* l;
  small* s;
  int newVal = 10;

  // assume all member of l and s are initialized properly

  modifyA(&l->s, 10);
  modifyA(s, 10);

  return 0;
}


Since small is the first member of large, you can cast large* to small* and pass that to modifyA.

If modifyA is passed a parameter declared as large *p that is a pointer to a large, then it can access the member a in the small as p->s.a. Is that what you want? Why do you show modifyA with a parameter small* s if you want it to have access to both the large object and its small member?

Or you can do modifyA(&mylarge.s, new_value) to get a pointer to the small member of a large object.

@EricPostpischil I think they want to be able to call the function on either a small or large.

@Barmar Yes, something like that. I added pseudocode but not sure if it is a valid one.

The code you added looks fine, assuming you allocate memory for l and s to point to. What's the problem?

&l->s should just be l->s now that you changed the large struct.

I thought I understood the question, but the code example shows that I don't.  It has two calls to modifyA, both passing a small * as the first argument.  And it could work almost as written, if only the l and s pointers actually pointed to objects.  What is the actual problem to be solved?

@JohnBollinger Look at the edit history, they changed the declaration of large.

I see that, @Barmar, and I'm still at "what is the problem to be solved?"  I don't follow how the code presented matches the prose description of what the OP wants.  The code doesn't have a "large as input to modifyA function."

Unrelated, but as a matter of style, l is a terrible name for a variable.

modifyA() takes a pointer to a small, and large has a member which is a small object, so you can simply pass a pointer to that member, eg:
large l;
...
modifyA(&l.s, 12345);

UPDATE: you changed the code in your question to make the large::small member be a small* pointer instead of a small object.  In which case, simply drop the & operator when passing that member to modifyA():
large* l;
...
modifyA(l->s, 10);


Sorry, I modified the large struct now with small* s instead of small s earlier. So modifyA(&l->s, 12345); will work?

No, as that would then be passing a small** pointer to modifyA().  You need to drop the & since l->s is already a small* pointer.

@SKPS Please don't make incompatible changes to a question after an answer has been posted.

Sorry, my knowledge on pointers is limited. Hence the confusion and purpose of the question. Your feedback is noted.

@SKPS it's ok to edit your question, but just don't CHANGE things that people were already referring to, as that risks invalidating comments/answers, making the discussion harder to understand for new readers that come along later. If you want to make changes, you should do it as an amendment at the end of the question, preserving the previous content. Or just post a new question with the different code.

Another option in C is to use the magic of generics:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct small {
    int a;
} small;

typedef struct large {
    small* s;
    int b;
} large;

void modifyA_small(small* S, int newVal) {
    S->a = newVal;
}

void modifyA_large(large* L, int newVal) {
    modifyA_small(L->s, newVal);
}

#define modifyA(X, newVal) _Generic((X), \
    small* : modifyA_small, \
    large* : modifyA_large \
    )(X, newVal)
    
int main(void) {
    small S = { 7 };
    large L = { &S, -3 };
    
    printf( "initial value of L.s->a = %d\n", L.s->a );
    
    modifyA( &L, 42 );
    
    printf( "final   value of L.s->a = %d\n", L.s->a );
    
    return 0;
}

The macro simply resolves to calling the correct function for the initial argument (named X in the macro). Hence, we get the desired output for the argument pointer:
initial value of L.s->a = 7
final   value of L.s->a = 42

